# Azure AD B2C - authorization code grant, profile_info response

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C with `Authorization code` grant. In the response after exchaning code for token, there is additional property `profile_info` with JSON encoded as Base64.

```
{
    "id_token": "<id-token>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1649069525,
    "id_token_expires_in": 3600,
    "profile_info": "eyJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJ0aWQiOiI5ZTAzN2IxNi05NzJmLTRmZWQtYmEyOC03MjU5MzJmOTNmNmQiLCJzdWIiOm51bGwsIm5hbWUiOm51bGwsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6bnVsbCwiaWRwIjpudWxsfQ",
    "scope": "openid"
}
```

I couldn't find any explanation in the docs what is the reasoning behind `profile_info`. In my case almost all properties in `profile_info` JSON are nulls.

```
{
  "ver": "1.0",
  "tid": "9e037b16-972f-4fed-ba28-725932f93f6d",
  "sub": null,
  "name": null,
  "preferred_username": null,
  "idp": null
}
```

Where are these values coming from? Are claims in `profile_info` and their values configurable using custom policy?
What's the intended use case for `profile_info` vs `id_token`?